# How to format Error message in Json Django

Tags: django

So, I want to format error messages in a json format instead of the HTML it is coming in.

models.py

```
# AUTH = Regex specified
class Player(models.Model):
    PLAY_MODE = [
        (1, "happy"),
        (2, "sad"),
    ]
    SEX = [
        (1, "Male"),
        (2, "Female"),
    ]
    

    auth = models.CharField(
        max_length=36,
        null=True,
        unique=True,
        validators=[AUTH, MinLengthValidator(36)],
    )
    area = models.ForeignKey(
        "master.Sport", on_delete=models.PROTECT, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)]
    )
```

serializer.py

```
 class Playererializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

The error format I want

```
{
  "type": "validation_error",
  "code": "invalid_input",
  "detail": "Crossing the maximum length",
  "attr": "auth"
}
```

It is coming in HTML format

views.py

```
def get_player(request, player_id):
    player = Player.objects.get(id=player_id)
    serializer = PlayerSerializer(user)
    # if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):   
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom exception handling](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling) as mentioned in the DRF documentation. For example, create a custom exception:

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    # Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    # Now add the HTTP status code to the response.
    if response is not None:
        response.data['type'] = response.default_code 
        response.data["code"] = response.status_code
        response.data["details"] = response.default_detail 
        response.data['att'] = str(exc)
    return response
```

Then add this to the `REST_FRAMEWORK` in the settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'my_project.my_app.utils.custom_exception_handler'
}
```

Comment: So like will i have to put validations in serializer again? And where do I put this custom handler. I'm new to django.

Comment: You can put the handler anywhere, for example here in /your_app/utils.py file. You don't need to modify validators in serializers. It should work with existing validation.

Comment: How do I call it? Should I call it in the views.py? Could you provide an example? This is how I have defined my view

Comment: You don't need to call anything, just add the code given here in settings.py, it will automatically take care of exceptions. Please see the documentation for more information.